# Django postgresql Datefield error

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm migrating a mysql database to postgresql in Django and have encountered the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "end_date" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp with time zone
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
```

The error is referring the this line in my model:

```
end_date = models.DateField()
```

The solutions online that I have found have been altering the sql directly, is there a way to correct the model in Django to work with the postgresql database?

Here is the full error, which occurs on migration:

```
Running migrations:
  Applying catalog.0006_auto_20141121_0419...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 108, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 139, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 455, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type, old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 601, in _alter_field
    params,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 103, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "end_date" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp with time zone
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
```

Comment: Did you specify a timezone in `settings.py`?

Comment: Adding a timezone didn't seem to have an effect

Comment: `DateField` should work work Postgres out-of-the-box. Are you getting this error when trying to run migrations or a script to import your data?

Comment: I'm getting the error when running migrations

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm out of time this evening, but you'll definitely want to post your migration code.

Comment: I have the same issue.    
 `migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='thing',
            name='due_date',
            field=models.DateField(),
            preserve_default=True,
        )`

Answer (score 1):

My work around was to
divide it to two migrations.

1 FAKE migrate your migration

2 comment out the field (remove from model)

3 migrate

4 uncomment field(add the field)

5 migrate